# Java Hibernate invalid mapping exception

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

My code was working just fine with the xml mapping then I changed to annotations and i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
```

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate1?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hibernate1</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mypassword</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="hibernate.Profesor" file="" jar="" package="" resource=""/>
        <mapping class="hibernate.Direccion" file="" jar="" package="" resource=""/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work for me changing only `connection.url`, `connection.username`, and `connection.password` with:

```
// A SessionFactory is set up once for an application
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
    .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Delete your mapping configuration files. That is, delete `Profesor.hbm.xml` and `Direccion.hbm.xml` if they still exist. You don't need them if you are using annotations.
If you are using Maven, make sure you have the following dependencies:

- [mysql-connector-java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java)
- [hibernate-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core)

Also, `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is deprecated. Use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.

It would be more helpful if you posted the exception's entire stack trace.